# unable to create a empty log file if exceptions are not there every day midnight

Tags: python, logging

unable to create a new empty log file if exceptions are not there every day midnight. can someone please help me
i tried for some any different changes but i didn't get the solution for creating a new file every midnight

```
import codecs
import glob
import logging
import logging.handlers as handlers
import os
import re
import time
from datetime import datetime
import getpass

import syslog


class RosCanTimedRotatingFileHandler(handlers.TimedRotatingFileHandler):
    """
    class overriding handlers.TimedRotatingFileHandler class
    to generate log files for every 5 min of clock time
    """
    try:
        def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):

            super(RosCanTimedRotatingFileHandler, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
            self.suffix = '%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M-%S.log'
            self.extMatch = re.compile(r"^\d{4}\d{2}\d{2}$")

            self.minutes = int(datetime.fromtimestamp(
                int(self.rolloverAt)
            ).strftime('%M'))
            self.seconds = int(datetime.fromtimestamp(
                int(self.rolloverAt)
            ).strftime('%S'))
            self.rolloverAt = self.rolloverAt - self.minutes % \
                              (self.interval / 60) * 60 - self.seconds


        def doRollover(self):
            # get the time that this sequence started at and make it a TimeTuple
            time_t = self.rolloverAt - self.interval
            time_tuple = time.localtime(time_t)
            if os.path.exists(self.baseFilename):
                os.rename(self.baseFilename, self.baseFilename.split('-')[0])
            self.baseFilename = self.baseFilename.split('-')[0]
            dfn = self.baseFilename+"-"+time.strftime(self.suffix, time_tuple)

            if os.path.exists(dfn):
                os.remove(dfn)
            if os.path.exists(self.baseFilename):
                os.rename(self.baseFilename, dfn)
            cur_time = datetime.now()
            current_timestamp = cur_time.replace(
                minute=(cur_time.minute - cur_time.minute % 5), second=0, microsecond=0
            ).strftime("%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M-%S")
            self.baseFile = self.baseFilename
            self.baseFilename = self.baseFilename +"-" + current_timestamp +".log"

            if self.backupCount > 0:
                # find the oldest log file and delete it
                files_list = glob.glob(self.baseFile + "-20*")
                if len(files_list) > self.backupCount:
                    files_list.sort()
                    os.remove(files_list[0])

            if self.encoding:
                self.stream = codecs.open(self.baseFilename, 'w', self.encoding)
            else:
                self.stream = open(self.baseFilename, 'w')

            time1 = datetime.now()
            current_time = time1.replace(
                minute=(time1.minute - time1.minute % 5), second=0, microsecond=0
            )

            current_time = time.mktime(current_time.timetuple()) + current_time.microsecond / 1e6

            new_rollover_at = self.computeRollover(current_time)

            while new_rollover_at <= current_time:
                new_rollover_at = new_rollover_at + self.interval

            self.minutes = int(datetime.fromtimestamp(
                int(new_rollover_at)
            ).strftime('%M'))
            self.seconds = int(datetime.fromtimestamp(
                int(new_rollover_at)
            ).strftime('%S'))

            self.rolloverAt = new_rollover_at - self.minutes % (self.interval / 60
                                                                ) * 60 - self.seconds
    except Exception as err:
        syslog.syslog("error in giles_log file of sync service: ",err)

LOGGER = logging.getLogger('tractor_init_config_manager')
LOGGER.setLevel(logging.INFO)

# Here we define our formatter
FORMATTER = logging.Formatter(
    '%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s'
)
LOG_PATH = "/opt/monarch/debug/"
TIME = datetime.now()
CUR_TS = TIME.replace(minute=(
        TIME.minute - TIME.minute % 5), second=0).strftime("%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M-%S")
FILE_PATH = "ros_can_logs/integration-" + CUR_TS + ".log"


def folder_exists(file):
    """checks directory exists or not.
                if directory is not existed create a directory."""
    try:
        path = os.path.dirname(file)
        if not os.path.exists(path.encode()):
            os.makedirs(path)
        test_message = "Initiating the logging...\n"
        with open(file, 'w') as f:
            f.write(test_message)

    except Exception as err:
        print(err)


folder_exists(LOG_PATH + FILE_PATH)
LOG_HANDLER = RosCanTimedRotatingFileHandler(
    LOG_PATH + FILE_PATH,
    when='midnight',
    interval=1,
    backupCount=10,  # 1File/Day
    delay=False
)
LOG_HANDLER.setLevel(logging.INFO)
# Here we set our logHandler's formatter
LOG_HANDLER.setFormatter(FORMATTER)

LOGGER.addHandler(LOG_HANDLER)


def info(msg):
    """to log the information message."""
    LOGGER.info(str(msg))


def error(msg):
    """to log the error message."""
    LOGGER.error(str(msg))
```

expecting to create a new empty log file if exceptions are not there every day midnight.

Comment: The logger does magically run itself if it is not called. If a day goes by without anything to trigger a logger call, then you'll have to schedule a job to do it.

Comment: i didnt get it, what should i add ?

Comment: You'll need to write a separate script that would create an empty log file named in the same format of `%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M-%S.log` if the file is found not to exist when the script is run by a job scheduler (such as `cron` in UNIX) at midnight everyday. This log file would not otherwise be created if your logger is not called at all during that day.

Comment: the above script creates log file but only if the exception is there, otherwise it is not creating any file

Comment: Exactly my point.

Comment: i need if there is no exception, still it should create log file

Comment: There is no magic to do that if the logger is not called. You simply need to write a separate script to create an empty log file yourself and run that script with a job scheduler.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can reach this with `FileRotatingFileHandler`. Here all 10 seconds. I think it must be possible to adjust this for 24 [hours](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.handlers.html#logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler) or a day according the documentation.

```
import logging
import time
from logging.handlers import TimedRotatingFileHandler
#----------------------------------------------------------------------
def create_timed_rotating_log(path):
    """"""
    logger = logging.getLogger("Rotating Log")
    logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
    
    handler = TimedRotatingFileHandler(path,
                                       when="S",
                                       interval=1,
                                       backupCount=5)
    logger.addHandler(handler)
    
    for i in range(6):
        logger.info("This is a test!")
        time.sleep(10)
#----------------------------------------------------------------------
if __name__ == "__main__":
    log_file = "timed_test.log"
    create_timed_rotating_log(log_file)
```